# Cannot convert from 'const int' to 'int &'

Tags: c++

I'm trying to execute the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
    int x;
public:
    A(int i = 25) { x = i; }
    int &f() const { return x; }
};

int main()
{
    A a(15);
    cout << a.f();
    return 0;
}
```

It creates an object called `a`, and the value of its `x` member is set to 15. However, when I try to call the function to return that value, I get an error. Why does it happen?

Answer (score 6):

You´re trying to return a reference to `x`, that means what´s
returned can be used to modify the `x` in the class object.

However, the method is `const`, meaning it isn´t allowed to modify anything within it´s own object.

Do you see the contradiction?
Either return a normal value without reference or remove the `const`

Comment: or add const in front

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to return a reference (which can be modified) from a member function marked `const` i.e. it cannot modify the class instance. Remove the trailing `const` and it will work. Or return a `const` reference instead.

Answer (score 0):

`const` member function will not modify internal members. If you return a reference to an int, `int&`, which can modify `x`, you're giving the opportunity to modify the value which is contradicting.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the reference from the return type

```
int f() const { return x; }
```

Also, the correct way of constructing is

```
A(int i = 25) : x(i) {}    /// Initialization list
```